# Joining a postgresql table of type "VarChar Array"?

Tags: postgresql

Until about 5 minutes ago I didn't even know you get a type VARCHAR that is also an array. How would I join these tables:

```
PEOPLE
ID | PERSON | GROUPS
1  | John   | {ONE,TWO}
2  | Jack   | {TWO}
3  | Jill   | {ONE,TWO,THREE}
4  | Jim    | {TWO,THREE}

GROUPS
ID    | TITLE
ONE   | First
TWO   | Second
THREE | Third
```

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
ID | PERSON | GROUP
1  | John   | ONE
1  | John   | TWO
2  | Jack   | TWO
3  | Jill   | ONE
3  | Jill   | TWO
3  | Jill   | THREE
4  | Jim    | TWO
4  | Jim    | THREE
```

How would I get this right in one query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular query, there's a syntax trick using `unnest()`, which allows to expand a single row into multiple rows when it's part of the select statement:

```
select id, person, unnest(groups) as grp
from people
```

I'm guessing you actually want First, Second, Third to appear rather than one, two or three, however. You can join like so:

```
with unnested_people as (
select id, person, unnest(groups) as grp
from people
)
select id, person, title
from unnested_people
join groups on groups.id = unseated_people.grp
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this ought to actually test and see for himself that the syntax trick works quite fine, e.g. `select 1 as a, unnest('{2,3}'::int[]) as b;`

Comment: Do note the bug I just reported, though: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1UmgtE-0002si-0x@wrigleys.postgresql.org :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote but why do you call that a "trick" as it was something... hidden?

Comment: @Denis It's not a bug, though it's certainly *ugly*. set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list are defined to work that way for horrid historical reasons. Now that 9.3 has real `LATERAL` support I'm hoping we can make SRF-in-SELECT a `WARNING` in 9.4.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto: I can't recollect seeing it documented anywhere in the PG docs. On the contrary, I'm quite sure I ran into it while reading the pg-hackers archives. The behavior probably explains why it's not obvious that you can do that in the docs.

Comment: @Denis the simplest example is to compare `select generate_series(1,2), generate_series(1,2);` with`select generate_series(1,2), generate_series(1,3);`. Essentially if the results are the same length Pg lines them up pair-wise, otherwise it's done like a join. It's some awful misfeature from the dark ages that we've been stuck with until `LATERAL` in 9.3. I agree that the docs (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) should discuss this properly and strongly warn that multiple SRFs in `SELECT` are deprecated.

Comment: @CraigRinger: it actually stops when it reaches the smallest common multiplier. :) http://www.mesoconcepts.com/2013/06/inconsistent-unnesting-in-postgresql/

Comment: @Denis Urgh, even worse. I only ever use it when I need synchronized pairings so I hadn't dug into the details of the non-equal case. Yick. We really need to make this a `WARNING`.

Answer (score 6):

`unnest` is unnecessary here, you can use a simple join with a test for array membership:

```
SELECT people."ID", people."PERSON", groups."ID"
FROM people
INNER JOIN groups ON groups."ID" = ANY (people."GROUPS")
ORDER BY people."ID", groups."ID";
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/5fa34/7

(The weird upper-casing is because I couldn't be bothered fixing SQLFiddle's inconsistent identifier quoting. It quotes column names but not table names.)

You can even use a GIN index on `people.GROUPS` and get an indexed join. The GIN index isn't cheap to build and is expensive to update so you'll only want to do that when you really need to, but it's useful. See the manual on array indexes. eg:

```
CREATE INDEX people_groups_gin_idx ON people USING GIN("GROUPS");

SELECT people."ID", people."PERSON", groups."ID"
FROM people
INNER JOIN groups ON ARRAY[groups."ID"] @> people."GROUPS"
ORDER BY people."ID", groups."ID";
```